# svn hangs resolving conflict in Cygwin

Tags: svn, cygwin

Since I upgraded one of my workstations to the svn client 1.7.2, whenever I am resolving a conflict the svn client hangs indefinitely when I am running in a Cygwin shell.

Here is what I am referring to...

```
$ svn update
Updating '.':
U    WEB-INF\src\drOps\TaskasaurusCoCPITServer.java
U    WEB-INF\src\drOps\TaskarooControlService.java
U    WEB-INF\src\log4j.properties
Conflict discovered in 'C:/data/tomcat/active/drOps/WEB-INF/classes/drOps/TaskasaurusCoCPITServer.class'.
Select: (p) postpone,
    (mf) mine-full, (tf) theirs-full,
    (s) show all options: mf
```

After choosing any option (mf, tf, p, or any of the options available after choosing s) the svn client hangs permanently.  I have to control + c out of it.

Has anyone seen this behaviour and know what might be causing it?

OS = Windows 7 Starter (32 bit) 
 
Subversion client version = 1.7.2

Comment: At least you have to use Subversion 1.7.4

Comment: And please add more information: OS, architecture of OS (and client), which svn client do you use. We aren't sensitives here in any way

Comment: Hi Badger.  I added the requested information.  Thanks.

Comment: If you know, how to define GUI-mergetool, try to use it (any).

Comment: 1. Try to checkout into fresh new Working Copy **before** GUI-way 2. Maybe delayed conflict-resolving *in current WC* (svn up  --non-interactive) may be acceptable temporary solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone still looking for a solution to this:

Resolving conflicts will not work on Cygwin with the Windows Subversion client. You need to use Cygwin's own subversion package. Run the [Cygwin installer](http://cygwin.com/install.html), install the "subversion" package.

After that, everything should run fine.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was that I use my svn client in a Cygwin Bash shell (important info I left out of original post).  If I instead use it in cmd.exe, everything is fine.

Comment: That doesn't really explain the problem though, does it? It's a workaround ;-)

Comment: I agree.  If someone finds a real answer I will gladly unaccept my own answer and accept theirs.  It would be nice if it worked in Cygwin as well.

Comment: I felt the same problem with byobu